# KeyboardExtension adjustTextPosition issues with emojis

Tags: ios, swift4, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm helping build a keyboardextension and I've recently run into an issue with Swift 4 and emojis. The new UTF-16 emoji support for Swift 4 is really nice but there is an issue with `adjustTextPosition` in `UIInputViewController`.

If we call `adjustTextPosition` to step over an emoji it will simply not step far enough, it seems like the characteroffset used by `UIInputViewController` doesn't match the character count used by the system.

To test simply write a text with emojis and whenever some key is clicked call:

```
super.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: 1)
```

What can be observed is that we have to click it more than what is to be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 5, it seems that the following code works well on iOS 12.

```swift
let count: Int = String(text).utf16.count
textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: count)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for safari, but it seems to work in other apps. So if you have an emoji and you want to step over it use utf16.count in order to find the right stepping amount. But for Safari your out of luck (it seems).

Comment: Oh, it's true. On safari, Sometimes it does not work and other times it works.

Comment: Safari/chrome (webkit) also has major issues with super.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput so I guess it fits perfectly.

Comment: @Warpzit I have reported this issue to https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ .

Comment: @Warpzit does my proposed solution work for you? Since there's no way to discriminate between safari and not safari, to act based on result looks like the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting caret position measured in grapheme clusters (Swift Characters):

```
func adjustCaretPosition(offset: Int) {
    guard let textAfterCaret = textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput else { return }
    
    if let offsetIndex = offset > 0 ?  textAfterCaret.index(textAfterCaret.startIndex, offsetBy: offset, limitedBy: textAfterCaret.endIndex) : textBeforeCaret.index(textBeforeCaret.endIndex, offsetBy: offset, limitedBy: textAfterCaret.startIndex),
        let offsetIndex_utf16 = offsetIndex.samePosition(in: offset > 0 ? textAfterCaret.utf16 : textBeforeCaret.utf16)
    {
        let offset = offset > 0 ? textAfterCaret.utf16.distance(from: textAfterCaret.utf16.startIndex, to: offsetIndex_utf16) : textBeforeCaret.utf16.distance(from: textBeforeCaret.utf16.endIndex, to: offsetIndex_utf16)
        textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: offset)
    }
    else {
        textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: offset)
    }
}
```

---

UPD: A messy hack, to try and fix Safari inconsistency. Since there's no way to discriminate between safari and not safari, to act based on result looks like the only solution.

```
func adjustCaretPosition(offset: Int) {
    // for convenience
    let textAfterCaret = textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput ?? ""
    let textBeforeCaret = textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput ?? ""
    
    if let offsetIndex = offset > 0 ?  textAfterCaret.index(textAfterCaret.startIndex, offsetBy: offset, limitedBy: textAfterCaret.endIndex) : textBeforeCaret.index(textBeforeCaret.endIndex, offsetBy: offset, limitedBy: textAfterCaret.startIndex),
        let offsetIndex_utf16 = offsetIndex.samePosition(in: offset > 0 ? textAfterCaret.utf16 : textBeforeCaret.utf16)
    {
        // part of context before caret adjustment
        let previousText = offset > 0 ? textAfterCaret : textBeforeCaret
        
        // what we expect after adjustment
        let expectedText = offset > 0 ? String(textAfterCaret[offsetIndex..<textAfterCaret.endIndex]) : String(textBeforeCaret[textBeforeCaret.startIndex..<offsetIndex])
        
        // offset in UTF-16 characters
        let offset_utf16 = offset > 0 ? textAfterCaret.utf16.distance(from: textAfterCaret.utf16.startIndex, to: offsetIndex_utf16) : textBeforeCaret.utf16.distance(from: textBeforeCaret.utf16.endIndex, to: offsetIndex_utf16)
        
        // making adjustment
        textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: offset)
        
        // part of context after caret adjustment
        let compareText = offset > 0 ? textAfterCaret : textBeforeCaret
        
        // rollback if got unwanted results
        // then adjust by grapheme clusters offset
        if compareText != "", expectedText != compareText, compareText != previousText {
            textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: -offset_utf16)
            textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: offset)
        }
    }
    else {
        // we probably stumbled upon a textDocumentProxy inconsistency, i.e. context got divided by an emoji
        // adjust by grapheme clusters offset
        textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: offset)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that "else" block execution is expected on Safari.
But, on my pseudo code, "offsetIndex, offsetIndex_utf16" is not "nil" and "if" block is executed actually.

Comment: @MitsuakiIshimoto I've updated the answer with a more messy solution, addressing Safari problem

Comment: Thank you so much! But it did not work for normal text fields expectedly.

Comment: Strange. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let correctedOffset = adjust(offset: offset)
textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPosition(byCharacterOffset: correctedOffset)

private func adjust(offset: Int) -> Int {
    if offset > 0, let after = textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput {
        let offsetStringIndex = after.index(after.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
        let chunk = after[..<offsetStringIndex]
        let characterCount = chunk.utf16.count
        return characterCount
        
    } else if  offset < 0, let before = textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput {
        let offsetStringIndex = before.index(before.endIndex, offsetBy: offset)
        let chunk = before[offsetStringIndex...]
        let characterCount = chunk.utf16.count
        return -1*characterCount
    } else {
        return offset
    }
}
```